# Is there a way to use PostSharp to make constructor parameters visible at the class level?

Tags: dependency-injection, constructor, postsharp, aop

Say I have a lot of boilerplate code like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly IDependencyA dependencyA;
    private readonly IDependencyB dependencyB;

    public MyClass(
        IDependencyA dependencyA,
        IDependencyB dependencyB)
    {
        if(dependencyA == null) throw ArgumentNullException("dependencyA");
        if(dependencyB == null) throw ArgumentNullException("dependencyB");
        this.dependencyA = dependencyA;
        this.dependencyB = dependencyB;

        ...
    }

    ...

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.dependencyA.DoSomething(this.dependencyB);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use something like PostSharp to remove the boilerplate code and make it look like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    [ConstructorParametersAreClassMembers]
    public MyClass(
        IDependencyA dependencyA,
        IDependencyB dependencyB)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.dependencyA.DoSomething(this.dependencyB);
    }
}
```

Is that even possible?

Aside: this is actually the way it works by default in F#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but not a very attractive method. I understand the pain. I find C# at this point a little to verbose. When applying the SOLID principles you get many small and focused classes. Since they are small, the overhead of writing constructors gets bigger.

But instead of using a code weaving tool such as PostSharp, you can also create a T4 template that generates the constructor for you. There is a [T4ConstructorGenerator](http://nuget.org/packages/T4ConstructorGenerator) NuGet package that adds a T4 template to your project, which generates a constructor for you.

With this template the following class:

```cs
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly ITimeProvider timeProvider;
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IOrderCalculator calculator;
    private readonly IMailSender mailSender;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // using the dependencies
    }
}
```

Will get the following constructor:

```cs
    public SomeService(
        ITimeProvider timeProvider,
        ILogger logger,
        IOrderCalculator calculator,
        IMailSender mailSender)
    {
        if (timeProvider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("timeProvider");
        if (logger == null)  throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        if (calculator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("calculator");
        if (mailSender == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("mailSender");

        this.timeProvider = timeProvider;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.calculator = calculator;
        this.mailSender = mailSender;

        this.OnCreated();
    }

    partial void OnCreated();
```

The template does this by adding a partial class, so the rest original code will not be affected. The template will only add a constructor when:

- The class (and its corresponding partial classes) does not have any constructor defined.
- The class is not static.
- The class contains one or more private fields.

In the case where your constructors often contain extra initialization (which in fact should be rare when doing Dependency Injection), you can simply implement the partial `OnCreated` method in the real class, as follows:

```
partial void OnCreated()
{
    // do logic here
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, but what happens if I need to run some kind of other initialization code in the constructor?  Perhaps I could change it so it calls a `private` parameterless constructor which I'm forced to implement.

Comment: The T4 template generates a partial class with constructor in its own file; it will not alter the original class (except that it might mark the class as 'partial'). If you need a 'custom' constructor, just add it to the class and the generated constructor will disappear. btw. It should be quite unusual to have any other initialization in your service classes when doing dependency injection.

Comment: Sure, but probably 90% of my constructors actually do some initialization in the constructor, so this wouldn't work.  I realize it can't create the constructor in the original file, but it would then fail to compile until I added one.  You'd have to modify the T4 script to ignore private constructors when deciding what classes to add partial classes for...

Comment: I'm not saying this method would work for every one, and you might need some tweeks to get this working for your situation, but it would probably be much harder to get this working with PostSharp. In my applications, this works on 95% of the classes. I wonder why you do so much initialization in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is just defensive programming in a method, which PostSharp or other AOP tools can certainly handle, but I look at that code and it seems like a symptom of something else going wrong in the architecture.

Are you using an Inversion of Control container/Dependency Injection tool (like StructureMap, Ninject, etc)?  If so, then it should handle wiring up the dependencies for you, and it will throw an exception if you forget to wire something up. So this reduces the need for all the defensive programming, while still allowing you to put other initialization code in the constructor.

Comment: The problem Scott tries to solve is to remove the verbosity that the C# compiler gives us. When you're following the SRP, classes get smaller, and the overhead of writing the constructor gets bigger. I must admit though, that I usually don't write any guard clauses from my constructors anyway, since my DI container will guarantee that a non-null value is injected. But still, all those constructor arguments must be mapped to private instance fields. I really like C# to evolve in this area, as [requested here](http://bit.ly/WqltjH), but I know this feature will never be added.